# Django doesn’t set STATIC_ROOT in settings.py

Tags: python, django, path, static

Trying to understand how “upload files” works I’ve seen that views.py doesn’t get values, assigned in settings.py relative to  STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL. But views.py  gets STATICFILES_DIRS’s value and this value is not correct.

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ""),]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [url(r'get_object/$', views.get_object, name = 'get_object'),]
```

**views.py**

```
def get_object(self):
   # static_files = settings.STATICFILES_DIRS
    static_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT

    if static_root:        
        path = static_root    
    else:
        path ='No object'

    return HttpResponse(path)
```

Django returns ‘No object’. When I type in in **views.py** static_files instead of static_root

```
def get_object(self):
    static_files = settings.STATICFILES_DIRS
    # static_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT

    if static_files:
        path = static_files
    else:
        path ='No object'

    return HttpResponse(path)
```

it returns 'C:/music/'. I guess this is not correct path. It gives correct path relative to BASE_DIR. I hope to get correct STATIC_ROOT. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you importing `settings` ? And are you sure you're using the right settings file (remember that `yourproject/settings.py` is just a default that can be overridden by command line arguments and environment variables).

Comment: Also and FWIW : 'statics' is for your project's assets (css, js, etc), not for uploaded contents that go to `media`.

Comment: Great thanks for your help! It's helped me. It was my fault not to see that there are two settings in my project.I confused them.